# indexOf of undefined error in parsing through cloud

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

Getting the error in below cloud function.

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    params[@"user"] = _sender_ID;
    params[@"recipientId"] = _owner_ID;
    params[@"message"] = msgToSend;
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendPushToUser" withParameters:params block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Push sent successfully

            NSLog(@"msg posted!");
        }
    }];
```

error:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
at main.js:15:35 (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.20)
```

Code for main.js is below.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushToUser", function(request, response) {
var senderUser = request.user;
var recipientUserId = request.params.recipientId;
var message = request.params.message;

// Validate that the sender is allowed to send to the recipient.
 // For example each user has an array of objectIds of friends
 if (senderUser.get("friendIds").indexOf(recipientUserId) === -1) {
response.error("The recipient is not the sender's friend, cannot send push.");
}

   // Validate the message text.
   // For example make sure it is under 140 characters
   if (message.length > 140) {
  // Truncate and add a ...
message = message.substring(0, 137) + "...";
  }

// Send the push.
// Find devices associated with the recipient user
var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
recipientUser.id = recipientUserId;
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.equalTo("user", recipientUser);

// Send the push notification to results of the query
Parse.Push.send({
where: pushQuery,
data: {
  alert: message
    }
  }).then(function() {
  response.success("Push was sent successfully.")
  }, function(error) {
  response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
  });
});
```

The above is the code written in main.js on cloud got the same from the link below. As far as i have understood from the error is that the problem is with the friendIds that's why it is not calling method 'indexOf'.

Got the idea from this link [blog](http://blog.parse.com/2014/09/03/the-dangerous-world-of-client-push/).

Comment: `main.js`?  `indexOf`?  contents of `msgToSend`?

Comment: check the blog link to understand these terms.

Comment: `main.js` is not defined there, and thus the use of `indexOf` cannot be identified.  And *your* code uses `msgToSend`, the contents of which you do not provide.

Comment: if you understand the problem can you provide any way for it.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that, contrary to what is asserted in the comments, that `senderUser` (that is, `request.user`) does not, in fact, have an array of friends stored in `friendIds`.

Without any information as to the contents of `senderUser` (for example, you may have just mis-spelled the name of the field), the best we can do is respond to the error more gracefully by adding this before the `if` generating the error:

```
if (senderUser.get("friendIds") === undefined) {
    response.error("The sender does not have any friends, cannot send push.");
}
```